# hieroglf package and writing glyphs one below the other

Tags: hieroglf

I tried searching for my answer but without any success.

I tried to write some numbers and using the ":" allows us to write glyphs below. But in my code all the hierolyphs are aligned :

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % permettent d'utiliser tous les caractères du clavier
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}  % on écrit en français ou en anglais
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry} % marges
\usepackage{pstricks,graphicx,pst-grad,xkeyval,pst-coil,ifthen,pst-blur}%indipensables pour bclogo
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}% pour écrire des maths
\usepackage{hieroglf,oands} % hiéroglyphes
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setenumerate[1]{label={\arabic*$\blacktriangleright$}}
    \setenumerate[2]{label={\alph*.}}

    \setitemize{label={\textbullet}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % en tête et pied de page
    \pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{eurosym} % symbole euro
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
Study carefully the following table.\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\pmglyph{6-6-{5-5-5}:{5-5}-4-4-3-3-2-{|-|}:{|-|}}& \pmglyph{5-5-4-4-{3-3}:3-2-2-{|-|}:{|-|}}\\
\hline
252214 & 22324 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: what I get]

You can see that there is a larger space where there should be a "go below".

Do you know how I can have some hieroglyphs below others ?
Thanks in advance.
Gaël

Answer (score 1):

you are using the french language. It redefines the colon, and this prevents it to work correctly in your command. Deactivate it with `\shorthandoff{:}` when needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % permettent d'utiliser tous les caractères du clavier
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}  % on écrit en français ou en anglais
\usepackage{hieroglf,oands} % hiéroglyphes


\begin{document}
Study carefully the following table.

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\shorthandoff{:}%
\pmglyph{6-6-{5-5-5}:{5-5}-4-4-3-3-2-{|-|}:{|-|}}& 
\shorthandoff{:}%
\pmglyph{5-5-4-4-{3-3}:3-2-2-{|-|}:{|-|}}\\
\hline
252214 & 22324 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello ! In fact I'm writing in english in that part, but I need the french somewhere else. Anyway, your solution is working so Thank you very much !